# What is a family of digraphs whose number of directed cycles grows exponentially?

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading Sedgewicks algorithms book, and in the chapter about digraphs, he asks "Describe a family of sparse digraphs whose number of directed cycles grows exponentially in the number of vertices". What exactly does he mean by that? I can't imagine a sparse digraph with more cycles than vertices unless they're self loops or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an `n`-cycle and make every edge a double edge. Now you have `2^n` cycles.

```
● ⇉ ● ⇉ ● ⇉ ... ⇉ * ⇉ (back to the first vertex)
```

If you don't like multiple edges, you can double each vertex like this:

```
● → ● → ● →     →
  ⤨  ⤨   ⤨ ... ⤨ (back to the first two vertices)
● → ● → ● →     →
```

The graphs are sparse, since we have just two edges per vertex.

Comment: You're right, I knew it had to be 2^n, but didn't know how to construct it, thanks!

Comment: Actually the second one is `2^(n/2)`. Still exponential though.

Comment: @ThomasAhle can you please explain to me the second example, i dont fully understand what you're trying to say there, in the first one i do agree that we get 2^n cycles, but in the second one i dont understand what you mean by "double each vertex" and why 2^(n/2)?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 it makes most sense if your browser supports the arrow from South West to North East crossing north west to South East.

Comment: @ThomasAhle oh, that's right, I just looked at it from Microsoft edge, google chrome doesn't seem to support this. Thanks!